# To check if element is not displayed in WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I want to write a test to make sure an element is not display ( I read the answer on stackoverflow, but doesn't solve my problem..)

I tried to use try and catch to do that, but the problem is is the element is exist, it will goto the catch ,and still pass the test.

```js
try {
  const element = await browser.driver.findElement(By.css(".element")).isDisplayed()
  expect(element).not.toBe(ture)
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).toBeTruthy()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Selenium documentation referring to [`findElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#findElement):

> This function should not be used to test whether an element is present
>   on the page. Rather, you should use [#findElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#findElements):

With this recommended solution:

```
driver.findElements(By.css('.element'))
     .then(found => console.log('Element found? %s', !!found.length));
```